# Reference to an url by using its Id in SQLite

Tags: android, sqlite, listview, android-sqlite, redirect

I am new, and I got stuck to a problem related to redirection of an url. I extracted some "Ids" and corresponding  "titles" and "urls" from a website using JSON format, and saved these to a SQLite database. I used an ID(autoincreamented) as primary key there.

I put all the "titles" in a list View and what I have to do is:

when anyone click on the title, it should be redirected to its corresponding url. I have a logic but am getting problem to implement it.

I thought of getting Position of the title clicked, then fetching the particular url from database using its ID(primary key) and then redirect it. but I couldn't implement it. I couldn't understand how to relate ID, title's position from listView and the corresponding url.

can someone please help me to solve this, or if any better suggestion to solve, for this kind of problem?

Comment: position from ListView isn't the id from your database. You can create adapter for your listview and fill it with data from database. Then after select item you can get object from your adapter and get it url property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend making a plain Java object of this format

```
public class WebLink {
    int id;
    String title, url;

    public String toString() { return this.title; } 

}
```

(Name the class what you wish, add setters, getters, etc.)

The important piece, in my opinion, is the toString method. Reason being that loading these objects into an `ArrayAdapter<WebLink>` will show the title without much extra work. For example, using the `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1` layout.

Then, if you can fill an Arraylist with these objects created from the full database row, then it's very straightforward to get the object from the adapter and have direct access to all that data.

All in all, don't query the database a second time (once for the list, and again to search for the title / id)

Comment: can you please clarify how to put whole row (id, Aid, title and url) into an arrayAdapter. what to specify here in the place of ?. (this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, ?)

Comment: You need an arraylist of object for that question mark. So, make an `ArrayList<WebLink>` objects from the database. i.e. `list.add(new WebLink(id, title, url))`, then stick that into custom adapter class that you make that extends `ArrayAdapter<WebLink>`. For all those details, you are welcome to see how to [define a custom adapter](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Using-an-ArrayAdapter-with-ListView#using-a-custom-arrayadapter)

Comment: Or... maybe you don't need all that... You just need the arraylist for the third parameter.